# How can I display custom data from the database in a View?

Tags: views, 8, database

I'm working to create a new website in Drupal 8 and cannot figure out how to reference custom table data within a View.

Specifically, I have a script that is taking data from an external DB and populating it into my Drupal DB into custom tables. How can I allow Views to see this data?

In Drupal 7 I have experience using the Forena module and the Data and Schema modules to accomplish same DB and external DB references, but what I'm finding is that support for these three modules in Drupal 8 appears to be lacking, making me think that there is a better way to do this in D8 that everyone knows about but me. :)

I'm not sure if I'm just not researching correctly, but I'm unable to find a clear answer about how to go about obtaining this functionality in Drupal 8. Drupal 8 is so different and I'm not sure if I should be looking for a contributed module or if this is something I would code directly.

Hopefully someone can point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Maybe [Views Custom Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yeah, I feel a bit silly now and was making this too difficult. There is a module for this for Drupal 8!

I was able to accomplish what I needed with [Views Custom Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table).

Thank you prkos for the comment.